# PHP - Eliminação de Registo acima de 10

Tags: php

Boas, Gostaria de obter a informação sobre a Eliminação de registos superiores a 10.
Isto é...

Se na database tiver 10, a função não funciona!
Se na database tiver acima de 10, apaga X registos antigos ate que fique novamente com 10.

Estou usando assim...

```
   $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT client_id FROM public_rewards WHERE client_id = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['u_id']);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($uid);
   $stmt->store_result();       

   if($stmt->num_rows > 5) {

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {          

            $remove_favorite = "DELETE FROM public_rewards WHERE client_id = '$uid' ORDER BY DESC";
        }           
   } else {
       return false;
   }
```

Fiquei um poucoi desorientado, pois essa função apaga TUDO! E eu não quero tudo.. apenas que fique com 10 recentes.

Comment: Já pensou em fazer algo como "delete from ... where id not in (select id from ... order by id desc limit 10)"?

Comment: Não existe um ID especifico... para apagar, apenas desejo apagar os mais antigos.. ate que fique com 10 apenas... Essa função ajuda em que...?

Comment: Excluir todos, mantendo os 10 mais recentes, baseado no id.

Comment: sim ID de UTILIZADOR...

Comment: fiz essa funçao e nao resultou..

Comment: $remove_bonus = "DELETE FROM public_rewards WHERE client_id not in (SELECT client_id FROM public_rewards ORDER BY client_id DESC LIMIT 5)";

Comment: Facil ficaria assim, mas ele simplesmente APAGA os 5 e deixa os restantes, e nao é isso que quero..                 $remove_bonus = "DELETE FROM public_rewards WHERE client_id = '$uid' ORDER BY client_id DESC LIMIT 5";